# Error: Program type already present: com.facebook.ads.Ad

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to implement facebook sdk according to this,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android

When I trying to compile it im getting this error.

> Error: Program type already present: com.facebook.ads.Ad

I'm using android studio 3.2.1

this is my gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true


        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1' // Required Dependency by Audience Network SDK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
    // More deps here //
}
```

Comment: Please post your app-level `build.gradle`.

Comment: Okay. done. I just added it

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537914/build-failed-program-type-already-present-com-facebook-ads-ad

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't find any answer there :( and that was 7 months ago.

Comment: As you can see [here -- the structure of facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk), you have duplicate APIs since you're trying to use SDK and core together. Remove `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'` and rebuild.

Comment: thank you very much jay. it's working. but will that be a problem to my facebook analytics ? they said to add it in before.

Comment: No, that won't be a problem.

Comment: @HiImNaru7o just small addition, use always same version of appcompat-v7 and recyclerview-v7.